# How to arrange templates and static files in Flask in same folder?

Tags: python, flask

I have a `Flask` app with a structure like this:

```
- static
  - js
      - template1.js
      - template2.js
      - other.js
  - css
      - template1.css
      - template.css
      - other.css

- templates
  - template1.html
  - template2.html

- server.py
```

I want to rearrange the structure like:

```
- static
  - js
    - other.js
  - css
    - other.css

- templates
  - template1
    - template1.html
    - template1.js
    - template1.css
  - template2
    - template2.html
    - template2.js
    - template2.css

- server.py
```

How do I declare I have static files inside template folder? And how to import `template1.js` and `template2.css` inside `template1.html`?

**template1.html**

```
# This works
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/template1.css') }}">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/template1.js') }}">

# How to import template1.js from template1 directory ?
```

Comment: In my opinion your structure doesn't make much sense. But use something like `app.static_folder = os.path.join(base_path, 'template/static')`

Comment: @patrickgerard there are two template directory. I want multiple static file path.